# how to get the values which is concatenated while inserting the data into database in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I have varchar type value in database with concatination of two types of EMail and contact number in Column "CONTACT" in "SUB" table like

```
 CONTACT
---------------------------
abc@gmail.com/4543654674
```

Now I want to separate this two format and i want to assign like

```
string Email="abc@gmail.com";

string phno="4543654674".
```

for that i am getting the string from table using linq as

```
var subDetails=context.SUB.Where(m=>m.Name="Christmas").FirstOrDefault();
```

Now I want to get that value

```
  string Email=subDetails.CONTACT;// Here I want to get only Email from Column

  string phno=subDetails.CONTACT;// Here I want to get only Phone number column
```

Please help me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx). Try below code

```
            string contact = "abc@gmail.com/4543654674";
            string[] contacts = contact.Split('/');

            string Email = contacts[0];
            string phno = contacts[1];
```

Comment: small correct we need to take string phno = contacts[1];